# BItwise operation in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = -10;
    printf("\%d\n",~x+1);

    return 0;
}
```

`~x + 1 = > 2's` complement of `X` .. I couldn't understand this

`x = 1111 1111 1111 1010`
one's complement of `x [~x] - 0000 0000 0000 0101`
Adding `1` to it `[~x + 1] - 0000 0000 0000 0110` which is not `10` but `6`. But the output above returns `10`.

Comment: Your walkthrough of the math starts with an incorrect assumption. `1111 1111 1111 1010` isn't -10, it's -6. (Which explains why `~x+1` aka `-x` returns 6 in your walkthrough.)

Comment: Adding to the above comment, -10 is `1111 1111 1111 0110`.